# iOS Photos removing individual face photo from People folder

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

How do I remove a photo that has accidentally been put in the wrong people photo album?

I have a photo of my dad (who is now deceased) that has appeared in the album for my father-in-law (who is very much alive). I can't find a way to remove an individual photo from the new people album once it is in it.

I don't want to hide the whole album of my father-in-law, just remove this one misfiled photo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select your father-in-law from the "People" album, tap the "Select" button in the upper right-hand corner, tap on the mislabeled photo, tap the "Share" icon in the bottom left, then from the list at the bottom of the screen select "Not This Person."

If you need to select multiple photos, check all applicable pictures from the scrollable list at the top of the Share sheet prior to pressing "Not This Person."

[image: not this person control in iOS photos]

If you don’t see this control, you are likely browsing photos from a location other than the People album. Use the back buttons in the top left to navigate all the way back to the top-level list of albums, then tap into the album corresponding to the person who has been wrongly identified in photos.

Comment: Have a screenshot? I'm not seeing the "Not this Person" option (iOS 10.0.1).

Comment: What a terrible UI. I would never have thought to search for this here. Thanks!

Comment: Asinine that we can only do this from the photo when within the "People" folder and not from the photo within any other UI location. https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: I agree that this is a very poor UI. I hope Apple fixes it soon.

Answer (score 3):

The "Not This Person" option only shows up if you select the person from the "People" album, and not through the Spotlight search.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15 in 2021 adds a new "Review Confirmed Photos" feature for removing potential wrong matches from a person's various photos/faces:

> Albums > People > select a person; "•••" > Review Confirmed Photos

[image: Review confirmed faces]

[image: Unselect photos]

Source: https://twitter.com/gregheo/status/1440052462673481730

Answer (score -1):

As above 'Select your father-in-law from the "People" album, tap the "Select" button in the upper right-hand corner, tap on the mislabeled photo, tap the "Share" icon in the bottom left, then from the list at the bottom of the screen select "Not This Person.". 
If you cannot see 'Not This Person' in the list, try swiping left to see more options or tapping 'More'

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the accepted answer?